# Undefined symbol: _ZTIN5boost7archive6detail14basic_oarchiveE

Tags: c++

I encountered this problem and failed to load a plugin for c++.
Is this a bug of boost lib?

Here is my code:

```
template <typename T>
bool enSerialize(const T& data, const std::string& filename) {
    std::ofstream ofs(filename.c_str(), std::ios::out);
    if (!ofs.is_open()) {
    return false;
    }
    else {
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
        oa << data;
    }
    ofs.close();
    return true;
}
```

and I called this one by

```
enSerialize(int(2), "test.txt");
```

Comment: Are you linking the boost serialization library as described in the documentation? Post your linker flags.

Comment: I guess I am linking correctly. I wrote several plug-ins. The serialization code for the others are working well.
If you wanna see the linking to boost...

set(boost_packages system filesystem program_options regex signals thread iostreams date_time)
find_package(Boost 1.36.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS ${boost_packages})

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})

Comment: I have no idea what build system that syntax is from... but I'm guessing your `boost_packages` line should include `serialization`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Etheranger is right.
I forgot to link to Serialization...
(how could this stupid fault happen...)

If you encountered the same problem,
include the following code in your cmakelists.txt

```
find_package(Boost 1.47.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS serialization system)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${libname} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Thanks a lot! Etheranger.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is using SCons, adding:

```
env.Append(LINKFLAGS = ['-lboost_serialization', '-lboost_system'])
```

fixed the issue for me.